# Why is nl_langinfo(CODESET) different from locale charmap?

Tags: c++, c, locale

This post originated from [How do you get what kind of encoding your system uses in c/c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492918/how-do-you-get-what-kind-of-encoding-your-system-uses-in-c-c)

I tried using

```
nl_langinfo(CODESET)
```

but I got ANSI_X3.4-1968 instead of UTF-8 (which is what I get when typing: locale charmap). Am I using nl_langinfo() wrong? How should I use it?

Comment: If you read the manpages in the original post's answers more thoroughly you wouldn't have run into this problem at all...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to first call

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

nl_langinfo always gives information about the current locale.

Comment: To expand on that, a C program always starts with the current locale as the "C" locale - the snippet in this answer is what you use to replace that with the system default locale.

Comment: This problem can appear in Yocto or anything that checks for the locale. You can export for example LC_ALL=export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

Comment: May be you can help? As written in Asterisk wiki - it uses default C strftime, wich uses nl_langinfo.
All locales are set, but when Asterisk uses this strftime (for saving file with current date and month) it ignores locale.

Comment: @romancev you already asked that at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76725730/asterisk-strftime-b so please don't hijack another question to ask your own.