# iconv C API: charset conversion from/to local encoding

Tags: character-encoding, locale, detection, iconv

I am using the iconv C API and I want iconv to detect the local encoding of the computer. Is that possible? Apparently it is because when I look in the source code, I find in the file [iconv_open1.h](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/libiconv.git/tree/lib/iconv_open1.h) that if the `fromcode` or `tocode` variables are empty strings (`""`) then the local encoding is used using the `locale_charset()` function call.

Someone also told me that in order to convert the locale encoding to unicode, all I needed was to use `iconv_open ("UTF-8", "")`

Unfortunately, I find no mention of this in the documentation.

And when I convert some iso-8859-1 text to the locale encoding (which is utf-8 on my machine), then during conversion I get errno=EILSEQ (illegal sequence). I checked and iconv_open returned no error.

If instead of the empty string in `iconv_open` I specify `"utf-8"`, then I get no error. Obviously iconv failed to detect my current charset.

edit: I checked with a simple C program that `puts(nl_langinfo(CODESET))` and I get `ANSI_X3.4-1968` (which is ASCII). Apparently, I got a problem with charset detection.

edit: this should be related to [Why is nl_langinfo(CODESET) different from locale charmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558379/whi-is-nl-langinfocodeset-different-from-locale-charmap)

additional information: my program is written in Ada, and I bind at link-time to C functions. Apparently, the locale setting is not initialized the same way in the Ada runtime and C runtime.

Comment: Any chance you can duplicate the problem in a ten-line test program?

Answer (score 1):

I'll take the same answer as in [Why is nl_langinfo(CODESET) different from locale charmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558379/whi-is-nl-langinfocodeset-different-from-locale-charmap)

> You need to first call
>
> ```
> setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
> ```