# Asterisk strftime %B

Tags: localization, asterisk, epoch, strftime

I want to record calls with mixmimonitor and save it with this format of the filename - %d-%B-%Y-%H:%M:%S.wav

%B - is the full month name (July for example) - it works, but I get the name of the month in English. What should I do to make Asterisk and strftime with EPOCH respect my locale?

P.S. Ubuntu 22.04.2 and Asterisk 18.10

Comment: Is LANG set in your environment? Is the language set on the channel?

Comment: Yes, everything is set. For example - voicemal message sends with correct month name via VM_DATE variable, have no clue why strftime don't

Comment: Showing your code might help

Comment: No prob, what code do you need?
But i think the problem in strftime itself - Asterisk uses standart c strftime and there is a brach with promlem, similar to mine
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558379/why-is-nl-langinfocodeset-different-from-locale-charmap

Comment: Asterisk use standart library for that code. Check source code. So something not okay with environment.

Comment: Yes, i know about that - i compiled little test program with this library - it's ok.
I even added my locale to LC_ALL but still no result(

Comment: Did you use `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` so that your program actually uses the locale in the environment? Without that all C programs start in the "C" locale and don't care about anything in the environment.

Answer (score 0):

So far this one is used with locale set to NULL:

```
const char *ast_setlocale(const char *locale)
{
        struct locale_entry *cur;
        locale_t prevlocale = LC_GLOBAL_LOCALE;

        if (locale == NULL) {
                return store_by_locale(uselocale(LC_GLOBAL_LOCALE));
        }

        AST_LIST_LOCK(&localelist);
        if ((cur = find_by_name(locale))) {
                prevlocale = uselocale(cur->locale);
        }

        if (!cur) {
                if ((cur = ast_calloc(1, sizeof(*cur) + strlen(locale) + 1))) {
                        cur->locale = newlocale(LC_ALL_MASK, locale, NULL);
                        strcpy(cur->name, locale); /* SAFE */
                        AST_LIST_INSERT_TAIL(&localelist, cur, list);
                        prevlocale = uselocale(cur->locale);
                }
        }
        AST_LIST_UNLOCK(&localelist);
        return store_by_locale(prevlocale);
}
```

Ast you can see here, it use LC_GLOBAL_LOCALE. which is linux global locale. You have check your system's settings.

Comment: According to /usr/bin/locale - all locales are set.
I even added LC_ALL locale - no result (
May be i can edit this code - can you say where i can find it?

Comment: main/stdtime/localtime.c:const char *ast_setlocale(const char *locale)

Comment: /usr/include/locale.h:# define LC_GLOBAL_LOCALE ((__locale_t) -1L)